# Verilog code for Multiply and Accumulate (MAC): Error: (vish-4014) No objects found

Tags: verilog, modelsim

While implementing the Verilog code you are seeing below, I have encountered an error message as follows:

```
 ** Error: (vish-4014) No objects found matching 'a'.
# Error in macro ./sim.do line 4
# (vish-4014) No objects found matching 'a'.
#     while executing
# "add wave a"
```

Can you tell how to fix the problem or where I do wrong?
The code is intended to do a multiply and accumulate task implemented on Model-sim SE-64 10.6d

```
//mac implemetation
    module mac(
    output reg[15:0] out,
    input[7:0] ina,inb,
    input clk,sclrn
    );
    endmodule

 //mac testbench
    `timescale 1ns /1ns
    module mac_tb();
    
    //togle clock
    reg clk;
    
    initial begin 
    clk = 0;
    forever #80 clk = ~clk;
    end
    
    reg sclrn;
    
    initial begin
    sclrn =0;
    #350 sclrn=1;
    end
    
    reg[7:0] a,b;
    wire[15:0] dout;
    
    mac DOT(.ina(a),.inb(b),.clk(clk),.sclrn(sclrn),.out(dout));
    
    endmodule
```

the sim.do file for simulation

```
vlib work
vlog mac.v mac_tb.v
vsim work.mac_tb
add wave a
add wave b 
add wave dout
add wave clk
add wave sclrn
run 1000
```

Comment: The mac module doesn't do anything. It's an empty module. There fore, my guess is that all signals that are used solely with that module have been trimmed and therefore, no longer exist.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix you are right but it has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 1):

Look in the ModelSim User manual for "Preserving Object Visibility" and add the switch it recommends.

Comment: thankyou all for trying to answer my question, the problem is in allowing Modelsim for auto-optimization, once you made a selection undo it works properly(us intention)  thankyou